# TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null Error checked in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-boot

Hello I am trying to put a checkbox but it gives me an error:

[TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3r2g.png)

I am programming a web application with javaScript, java, html, spring boot, but I get that error. This is my code:

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ck" name="ckbox" data-bind="checked: selection">
```

JavaScript

```
class PdViewModel {
    constructor() {
        var self = this;
        
        self.selection = document.getElementById("ck").checked;
        
        self.message = ko.observable(null);
        self.error = ko.observable(null);
        
        // Header Config
        self.headerConfig = ko.observable({
            'view' : [],
            'viewModel' : null
        });
        
        moduleUtils.createView({
            'viewPath' : 'views/header.html'
        }).then(function(view) {
            self.headerConfig({
                'view' : view,
                'viewModel' : app.getHeaderModel()
            })
        })
    }


modifypd() {
        var self = this;
        let info = {
            selection : this.selection()
        };
        let data = {
            data : JSON.stringify(info),
            url : "pd/modify/",
            type : "put",
            contentType : 'application/json',
            success : function(response) {
                self.message("Change");
            },
            error : function(response) {
                self.error(response.responseJSON.errorMessage);
            }
        };
        $.ajax(data);
    }
```

Then I want that value to save it in a registry in mysql using a spring postmapping.
And then collect that value and show it. Can you help me?

Comment: are you dynamically creating your html markup?

Comment: Check the documentation for [`.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) when it returns `null` and you should find the problem. For an actual answer we need a [mcve] -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Why are you still using the old, pre-ES6 `self = this` trick? You don't need that

Comment: if I change byId to byName it gives me the error of product.js: 125 Uncaught TypeError: this.selection is not a function

Comment: Hello. Please put content as text, not as image.